# FFT library for Arduino 101?

Tags: library, 101

I am currently trying to get a real-time FFT working for a project on an Arduino 101 which uses the Intel Curie chip. All the FFT libraries (if any) seem to be for the Arduino Uno and architecture dependent (most of them have assembly stuff for optimization).

I was wondering if there is any robust, up do date and most importantly working (with the latest Arduino 101) library. I have tried the PlainFFT library which I read might be compatible with the Arduino 101 (https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=409791.0).

However this library seems to be out of date, using old extensions of sketch files and old library names in its code (I could not get it to work). Alternatively I wanted to try and tailor a pure C code such as https://github.com/jtfell/c-fft, which seems to have its own Makefile for compilation (this one uses a C99 compiler). I could compile and use this code on a Linux terminal but I am not sure how to go on about making it run inside an Arduino sketch.

Answer (score 1):

I used lightweighted **KissFFT** (Mark Borgerding) at Arduino Mega and seems it is pure C code so should be running anywhere.

Comment: So when I get this library from let's say https://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/?source=typ_redirect how do I then use it in an Arduino sketch? Just putting it in the libraries folder and #include it in the sketch (.ino) will not work. What adjustments will I need to make?